# Калькулятор с использованием maskedtextbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Только изучаю C#, стоит задача - сделать калькулятор времени с использованием формы.

Решила остановиться на maskedtextbox в качестве полей для ввода и вывода времени в формате чч:мм:cc.

Но не могу точно разобраться как обрабатывать вводимые данные в этих полях.

Вот так выглядит моя форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В прослушивании кнопки "Посчитать" с помощью Switch и case расписала производимые операции.
Но у меня проблема с объявлением переменных, какого типа данных они должны в таком случае быть?

Код при прослушивании:

```
{
    int a, b;
    a = Convert.ToInt16(maskedTextBox1.Text);
    b = Convert.ToInt16(maskedTextBox2.Text);

    switch (comboBox1.Text)
    {
        case "+":
            maskedTextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(a + b);
            break;
    }
}
```

Выходит ошибка: `Входная строка имела неверный формат`

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(maskedTextBox1.Text)` покажет вам, в каком формате эта строка. Это явно не число, поэтому его не может пережевать `Convert`.

Comment: @aepot в сообщении выводится заданное мной число в maskedTextBox1 - 10:00:00 то есть dateTime, если я задаю этот типа данных для a и b, то выходит ошибка при заданной операции сложения, так как нельзя складывать два значения данного типа.

Comment: А вот операцию "вычитание" воспринимает нормально через case.

Comment: сделайте сложение через вычитание тогда))) а - (-б)

Comment: `Convert.ToInt16` - это попытка преобразования в `short`, а не в `DateTime`. Кстати да, `int` - это `Int32` :) Вам нужно что-то типа этого тогда `DateTime a = DateTime.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text)`. Если речь про время, то даже наверное проще использовать `TimeSpan`, а не `DateTime`.

Comment: Покажите используемые маски.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по описанию, вы хотите считать время. Для этого можно использовать тип `TimeSpan`.

Судя скриншоту, вы используете следующие маски: `"00:00:00"`.

Содержимое свойства `Text` контрола `MaskedTextBox` будет зависеть от значения `TextMaskFormat`. По умолчанию оно равно `MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals`.

В таком формате его можно напрямую распарсить с помощью методов `Parse` или `TryParse`.

Код может выглядеть примерно так:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan1 = TimeSpan.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text);
TimeSpan timeSpan2 = TimeSpan.Parse(maskedTextBox2.Text);

TimeSpan result = timeSpan1 + timeSpan2;

maskedTextBox3.Text = result.ToString();
```